# where does the saved file go java

Tags: java, list

I have a method

```
 public void save(String filename)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filename)));

        for(Track item : thePlayList)
        {
            item.save(bw);
        }
        bw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("couldn't save M3U file " + filename);                   
    }
```

and I have this in the main method, I would like to know where does the saved file go ?  if not then how to save the file in a specific folder.

```
combine.save("combined");
```

Comment: by default, it will be saved in folder where you run your program. you can specify it by including the folder path in your file name. for example, `String filename= "D:/document/filename.txt";`

Comment: I don't know.  What does `Track#save` look like?  It would **seem** that it'd save it wherever `filename` points to, but I can't be entirely certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specified without a path, Java is going to write the file into the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). You can always determine where that is with something like this

```
File file = new File(filename);
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());  // <-- should print the full path to the file
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

You can also specify a full path when you call your method, for example -

```
 combine.save("C:/combined"); // <-- or C:\\combined
```

or a relative path, for example -

```
 combine.save("./output/combined"); // <-- or ../output/combined
```

Answer (score 3):

The file will be saved in within the execution context of the application - in other words, the directory you ran it from...

For example...

If you ran the program from `C:\MyJavaProgram`, then it will be saved within this directory